# Удаление элементов массива через месяц

Tags: javascript, node.js

Хотел бы узнать, возможно ли реализовать функцию которая будет удалять элементы массива  обьектов  через месяц? Может некоторым этот вопрос покажется странным, но все же. Если это возможно то, покажете мне путь решения.
Просто я пишу своего тг бота, которому  эта функция была бы полезна.

Использовал метод setInterval,значение оказалось слишком большими для работы с ним.

Буду благодарен за предоставленный ответ.

Comment: `CRON` / `Очереди`

Comment: где "хранится" ваш массив?

Comment: Не понял суть вопроса?

Comment: не знаю как спросить проще... массив в памяти приложения? в базе данных? в редисе? в файле json? где существует "массив" во время когда приложение запущено? где существует "массив" во время когда приложение остановлено?

Comment: Тогда, в памяти приложение

Comment: тогда в "элементе массива" должен храниться expires - время, до которого удалять "'элемент" нельзя. а дальше - при вызове какого-то сценария чистить этот массив по просроченным элементам. а можно не при вызове сценария, а поставить node-cron|node-crontab|etc. только всё это - дурацкие практики так как при остановке приложения все данные пропадут

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Про "дурацкие практики" я еще подумаю.Буду использовать БД скорее всего.